# Can we make a reminder to mark answers as accepted?

Tags: feature-request

I have seen a problem on Ask Ubuntu. Many times, people forget to mark an answer as accepted, even if its the **only one and it does work**. Is there a way to add a seven-day reminder like "Mark an answer in [this question] as accepted!" Maybe an inbox notification:

```
Hey! You forgot to mark an answer! Come back and mark one that works!
```

Would this be
a) doable
and
b) practical ?

I'm just thinking that there's a lot of reputation missing because people aren't marking working answers as accepted.

This is like [Encouraging (new) users to accept answers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2869/encouraging-new-users-to-accept-answers)

but, even 1rep users (the abandoners) should accept answers. Maybe an email reminder (okay, this *may* be too far)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is already that:

[image]

Comment: welll. I only ever asked one question. But still, about the "abandoners"?

Comment: Also, if you are the OP and you vote on an answer, a popup appears letting you know you can/should accept the answer too.